# Shell script to call external program which has user-interface

Tags: linux, shell, io

### I have an external program, say a.out, which while running asks for an input parameter, i.e.,

./a.out

Please select either 1 or 2:

1. this will do something
2. this will do something else

---

Then when I enter '1', it will do its job. I don't have the code itself but just binary so can't change it. 
I want to write a shell script which runs a.out and also inserts '1' in.

### I tried many things including silly things like:

./a.out 1

./a.out << 1

./a.out < 1

### etc.

but don't work. 
Could you please let me know if there is any way to write such as shell script?
Thanks,
dbm368

Comment: @nosid, that method works in bash and ksh, but not dash (Ubuntu's /bin/sh), and by extension is probably not portable to other *nix systems.  What is that approach called and where is documented?

Comment: The syntax with `<<<` is known as Here Strings (related to Here Documents). It is supported by `bash`, which is the only shell I am using on Linux. It is documented in the bash man page.

Comment: ./a.out 1: this will pass 1 as an argument, not what you want.  ./a.out<< 1: this is a here-document. ./a.out < 1: this reads input from the file called '1'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a pipe.  For example:

```
echo 1 | ./a.out
```

In general terms a pipe takes whatever the program on the left writes to `stdout` and redirects to the `stdin` of the program on the right.